# How to make new raster with higher values than the older one?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster-calculator, elevation

I'm working in ArcGIS and I have an elevation model of seaside. What I should do is to model an uplift of land, so make a new raster dataset in which will be higher values (for example to make a new dataset where all the values for land, not for sea, will be 1 meter higher). Please, do anybody know how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Con function](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/con-.htm) in the raster calculator:

```
Con("elevation raster" > 0, "elevation raster" + 1, "elevation raster")
```

This means `if a pixels value is greater than zero, the new value will be pixel + 1, else pixel value stays the same`